# Obter tempo de resolução de nome em pedido HTTP

Tags: java, android, http, http-request, dns

Viva,

É possível obter o tempo de resolução de nome separado do tempo de acesso?
O código que tenho é:

```
HttpURLConnection connection;
try {
    URL endereco = new URL(url);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) endereco.openConnection();
    ...
```

é possível dividir o openConnection de forma a tirar os tempos 1º da resolução do nome ao servidor DNS e 2º o tempo de acesso?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voce pode utilizar o [`InetAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) para fazer a resolução do nome antes de fazer a conexão.

```
InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("pt.stackoverflow.com");
```

A partir disto, pode fazer a conexão com o endereço `IP` que foi resolvido, utilize o método [`getHostAddress`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress--) para obter o `IP`:

```
URL endereco = new URL("http", inetAddress.getHostAddress(), "/");
```

Observe que ao criar a [`URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) não utilizei o mesmo construtor do seu exemplo, pois somente o IP não fornece todas as informações necessárias para que seja feita a conexão, então utilize um [construtor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#constructor.summary) que atenda a necessidade.

Comment: +1 - perfeito, se for analisar bem a resolução de nome não faz parte do HTTP em si

Comment: Obrigado, outra dúvida, aquando do connect, ele tb não vai fazer a resolução de nome incorporada? Fazendo com esta solução a resolução 2x?

Comment: Neste caso não, pois o `inetAddress.getHostAddress()` irá retornar o IP do host, e não haverá necessidade de outra resolução de nomes.

Comment: a minha pergunta era e ao fazer: 

    `connection = (HttpURLConnection) endereco.openConnection();
    ...
    BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());`

Não vou estar a fazer de nova a resolução de nome aquando da conexão?

Comment: Não irá fazer, pois você está utilizando o IP para fazer a conexão.

Comment: Obrigado Henrique, resposta aceite ;)